# Flask/SQLAlchemy: TypeError: Incompatible collection type: tuple is not list-like

Tags: python

I have been staring at this error message all day. I have an Employee model and am receiving this error when attempting to add a new employee. I have it set up so the employee table is directly linked to the user table (one employee per user account), therefore the employee table's primary key is a foreign key from the users table. This code was working as-is until a recent update to the model, and I am not sure what I changed that would have caused this error. The data being passed in seems to be correct, but I am getting an internal server error (500) when trying to add the employee this way.

Model code:

```
class Employee(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    alias_first_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    alias_last_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    country_code = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    linkedin_url = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    availability = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    zipcode = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    direct_report = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)
    employment_start = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False)
    employment_end = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=True)
    recruiter_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    hourly_rate = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'first_name': self.first_name,
            'last_name': self.last_name,
            'status': self.status,
            'alias_first_name': self.alias_first_name,
            'alias_last_name': self.alias_last_name,
            'role': self.role,
            'country_code':self.country_code,
            'phone_number':self.phone_number,
            'email':self.email,
            'linkedin_url':self.linkedin_url,
            'availability':self.availability,
            'address':self.address,
            'city':self.city,
            'state':self.state,
            'country':self.country,
            'zipcode':self.zipcode,
            'direct_report':self.direct_report,
            'employment_start':self.employment_start,
            'employment_end':self.employment_end,
            'recruiter_name':self.recruiter_name,
            'hourly_rate':self.hourly_rate,
            'rating':self.rating,
        }

    skill = db.relationship("Skill", back_populates="employee", cascade='all, delete')
    rating = db.relationship("Rating", back_populates="employee", cascade='all, delete')
    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="employee", cascade='all, delete')
    experience = db.relationship("Experience", back_populates="employee", cascade='all, delete')
    file = db.relationship("File", back_populates="employee", cascade='all, delete')
```

Employee route (error occurs here):

```
@employee_routes.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    """
    Creates a new employee
    """
    form = EmployeesForm()
    form['csrf_token'].data = request.cookies['csrf_token']
 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        id=form.data['id'],
        first_name=form.data['first_name'],
        last_name=form.data['last_name'],
        status=form.data['status'],
        alias_first_name=form.data['alias_first_name'],
        alias_last_name=form.data['alias_last_name'],
        role=form.data['role'],
        country_code=form.data['country_code'],
        phone_number=form.data['phone_number'],
        email=form.data['email'],
        linkedin_url=form.data['linkedin_url'],
        availability=form.data['availability'],
        address=form.data['address'],
        city=form.data['city'],
        state=form.data['state'],
        country=form.data['country'],
        zipcode=form.data['zipcode'],
        direct_report=form.data['direct_report'],
        employment_start=form.data['employment_start'],
        employment_end=form.data['employment_end'],
        recruiter_name=form.data['recruiter_name'],
        hourly_rate=form.data['hourly_rate'],
        rating=form.data['rating']

        # this is where the error points
        new_employee = Employee(
            id=id, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, status=status, alias_first_name=alias_first_name,
            alias_last_name=alias_last_name, role=role, country_code=country_code, phone_number=phone_number,
            email=email, linkedin_url=linkedin_url, availability=availability, address=address, city=city,
            state=state, country=country, zipcode=zipcode, direct_report=direct_report, employment_start=employment_start,
            employment_end=employment_end, recruiter_name=recruiter_name, hourly_rate=hourly_rate, rating=rating
        )
    
        db.session.add(new_employee)
        db.session.commit()
        return new_employee.to_dict()
    elif form.errors:
            return {'errors': validation_errors_to_error_messages(form.errors)}, 401
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        employees = Employee.query.all()
        return {"employees": [employee.to_dict() for employee in employees]}
```

Flask form:

```
class EmployeesForm(FlaskForm):
    id = StringField('id', validators=[DataRequired()])
    first_name = StringField('first_name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('last_name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    status = StringField('status')
    alias_first_name = StringField('alias_first_name')
    alias_last_name = StringField('alias_last_name')
    role = StringField('role', validators=[DataRequired()])
    country_code = StringField('country_code', validators=[DataRequired()])
    phone_number = StringField('phone_number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    linkedin_url = StringField('linkedin_url')
    availability = StringField('availability', validators=[DataRequired()])
    address = StringField('address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = StringField('city', validators=[DataRequired()])
    state = StringField('state', validators=[DataRequired()])
    country = StringField('country', validators=[DataRequired()])
    zipcode = StringField('zipcode', validators=[DataRequired()])
    direct_report = StringField('direct_report')
    employment_start = StringField('employment_start', validators=[DataRequired()])
    employment_end = StringField('employment_end')
    recruiter_name = StringField('recruiter_name')
    hourly_rate = StringField('hourly_rate')
    rating = StringField('rating')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the block that begins `if form.validate_on_submit():`, you have commas after each assignment. That makes each value a tuple. Try printing `id` or any other variable and you'll see it is a 1-item tuple, not the value you expected. The later statement is complaining that you passed it a tuple when it wanted a list.

Take the commas out.

Comment: This gives me a similar error saying "None is not list-like." My other API routes are written in the same way and do not throw this error.

Comment: Well, which of the variables is `None`?

Comment: Variables are passed in from a frontend React form, some with a value of null. However, this should not be a problem, because those are nullable fields.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a different problem, then. Post a new question.